# How to use usermodel from mainApp in custom engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I've created an RoR-App and I want to add a simple blog as engine that is already mountet to /blog where users can have their own blog. Now I didn't find anything how I can use the model user.rb in my blog engine.

In my main app I can use `current_user.username` but in my engine I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to achieve this:

1. Inherit your controller class from the main application's `ApplicationController`:

   ```
   class MyEngine::ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
   end
   ```

   This way it will have access to all the same helpers that have already been configured there. As a downside, this might drag in unwanted functionality, too.
2. Manually include the Devise controller helpers:

   ```
   class MyEngine::ApplicationController
     include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
     define_helpers(Devise.mappings[:user])
   end
   ```